# c++ калькулятор

Tags: c++

При отладке выводит "Использование неинициализированной памяти", как решить сею проблему?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    float a, b, c;
    char d;
    int q;
    cout << "Welcome to calculator" << endl;
    cout << "1 => Launch Calculator \n 2 => Complete programm \n" << endl;
    cin >> q;
    if (q == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter num 1 >> ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter selected action";
        cin >> b;
        cout << endl;
        if (d == '+')
        {
            c = a + b;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
        else if (d == '-')
        {
            c = a - b;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
        else if (d == '*')
        {
            c = a * b;
            cout << c << endl;
        }
        else if (d == '/')
        {
            c = a / b;
            cout << c << endl;
            try
            {
                if (b == 0)
                    throw 123;
            }
            catch (int x)
            {
                cout << " Error number " << x << " >> divide by 0!" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (q == 2)
            cout << "Goodbye";
            cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы считываете две переменные — числа `a` и `b`. Но не считываете знак действия `d`.

Считывайте и его, и будет `d` инициализированной...

Кстати, вы пишете:

```
cout << "Enter selected action";
cin >> b;
```

Но судя по коду, вы все же записываете в `b` второе число...

Comment: огромное спасибо, я видать слепой малёха